# How to set the scale of a THREE.Sprite to a width in pixel units?

Tags: three.js

I have a viewer with a perspective camera. I know the size of the viewer and the pixel ratio. I have several sprites in my scene that use the .sizeAttenuation property to never change size.

With all of this, I want to be able to set the scale of the sprite instances to, for example, be 20px x 20px. Is that possible? Is there a known conversion from pixels to sprite scale?

What I am experiencing now is that the sprites will change size depending on the viewer size. I wish to know how to resize them when the viewer changes so they are consistently the same size.

thanks!